# Using sockets winapi with Qt

Tags: qt, winapi, winsock2, wsastartup

I am using an API of communicating with remote server and it's only available in `C`. I cannot rewrite it, because it's a very specific protocol, and it'll take too much effort.

The API providedIt uses standard Winsock2 scheme. So, in order to work with it I added

```
LIBS += C:\\QtSDK\\mingw\\lib\\libws2_32.a
```

to my project's .pro file.

However, when the program accesses any WinSock function, even `WSAStartup`, it crashes immediately with the error message `SIGILL -- Illegal Instruction`. 
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1 for "it crashes immediately". For the love of god, please tell us what the real error message was!

Comment: SIGILL -- Illegal Instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling this API yourself or do you have it as an object/header pair? If by yourself, is it with `QtSDK\MinGW`? Do you point it to the winsock headers of `MinGW`?

A good first test would be to try and compile a simple driver `main` using this library, with `QtSDK\MinGW` as standalone, without Qt's `qmake`. Once you make *that* work, porting into your Qt project should be easy.

Comment: I add it as sources + headers, so it's compiled together with the project.

Comment: can you compile it separately and link properly to make it work, without Qt?